# D6 - Trying to display variable_get()s in a block

Tags: 6, blocks, configuration, theming

I am trying to display 4 variables in a custom block(created from my custom module). I am accessing the variables using variable_get('$myvariable', '0').

I am not able to display the array in the block "$content" - is my code not handling the renderable array properly?

```
 function neil_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()) {
switch ($op) {
case 'list':
  return array(
    0 => array(
      'info' => t('Custom Neil Block'),
    ),
 );

case 'view':
    $subject = '';
    $content = '';
    switch ($delta) {
        case 0:



          $block_content = "";

          $block_content = array(
            'content'   =>  array(
                'blockvar_progress_so_far'          =>            variable_get('progress_so_far', '0'),
                'blockvar_number_of_projects'       => variable_get('number_of_projects', '0'),
                'blockvar_dollars_raised'           => variable_get('dollars_raised', '0'),
                'blockvar_number_children_impacted' => variable_get('number_children_impacted', '0'),

            ),
          );

          $content = $block_content;
          $subject = t('Subject in My Custom Block');
        break;
    } 

    }
return $block;
break;
```

}
}

Instead of the "$block_content", I only see the following: "Array"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the output of the block content as a string, not an array.

```
...
case 'view':
  $subject = '';
  $content = '';
  switch ($delta) {
    case 0:
      $subject = t('Subject in My Custom Block');
      $content =
        'blockvar_progress_so_far = ' . variable_get('progress_so_far', '0') . '<br />' .
        'blockvar_number_of_projects = ' . variable_get('number_of_projects', '0') . '<br />' .
        'blockvar_dollars_raised = ' . variable_get('dollars_raised', '0') . '<br />' .
        'blockvar_number_children_impacted = ' . variable_get('number_children_impacted', '0');

      // Return values so they can be inserted into block
      return array(
        'subject' => $subject,
        'content' => $content,
      );
    break;
  }
...
```

See documentation on Drupal 6's [hook_block()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_block/6) for a more detailed example.

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning anything to the `$block` variable. Take a look at the following snippet from the [Block example module](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/block_example!block_example.module/6).

```
case 'view':
  // If $op is "view", then we need to generate the block for display
  // purposes. The $delta parameter tells us which block is being requested.
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'configurable-text':
      // The subject is displayed at the top of the block. Note that it
      // should be passed through t() for translation.
      $block['subject'] = t('Title of configurable-text block');
      // The content of the block is typically generated by calling a custom
      // function.
      $block['content'] = block_example_contents(1);
      break;
    case 'empty':
      $block['subject'] = t('Title of block #2');
      $block['content'] = block_example_contents(2);
      break;
  }
  return $block;
```

In your case it would be:

```
  case 0:
    // other code here
    $block['subject'] = t('Subject in My Custom Block');
    $block['content'] = $block_content;
  break;
  // etc
```